# Spring mvc multipart

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I keep getting the following error

> org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MissingServletRequestPartException: Request part 'model' not found.

When posting multipart request to spring mvc controller.

This is the request:

```
Accept:application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Charset:ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:4394941
Content-Type:multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryK4y8t7mg2SNoYxC4
Cookie:SID=091f182f-5534-47c4-b0c1-8ca9c17e1f09
Host:localhost:8080
Origin:http://localhost:8080
Referer:http://localhost:8080/controller/home/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/24.0.1312.57 Safari/537.17
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
Request Payload
------WebKitFormBoundaryK4y8t7mg2SNoYxC4
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="model"

{"name":"kjkjk","description":"kkjkjk"}
------WebKitFormBoundaryK4y8t7mg2SNoYxC4
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="photo"; filename="IMG_1281.JPG"
Content-Type: image/jpeg
```

**Controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/t")
    public ResponseEntity<ResponseMessage> t(@CookieValue(value = "SID", required = true) String sessionId, 
            @RequestPart("model") CategoryModel model,
            @RequestPart("photo") MultipartFile file)
    {
    return new ResponseEntity<ResponseMessage>(new ResponseMessage(200, "success"), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

**Model**

```
package bla.bla.bla;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Vector;
import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonBackReference;
import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonIgnore;

public class CategoryModel {

    public CategoryModel(String id, String name, String description, CategoryModel parent) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
        this.id = id;
        this.parent = parent;
    }

    public CategoryModel(String id, String name, String description, CategoryModel parent, List<CategoryModel> childrens) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
        this.id = id;
        this.parent = parent;
        this.childrens = childrens;
    }

    public CategoryModel()
    {

    }
    public String id;
    public String name;
    public String description;
    public String imageUrl; 
    public CategoryModel parent;
    public List<CategoryModel> childrens = new ArrayList<CategoryModel>();
}
```

I have added controller and entity please do check and let me know where am I going wrong?

Thank you,
James

Comment: Could you clarify how you have setup your multipartResolver bean? http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.0.RC1/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-multipart

Comment: this is the configuration:
<bean id="multipartResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver"/>

Comment: what does your jsp form look like?

Answer (score 5):

I also had a similar problem and fortunately, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25183266/2494102) answer helped me to figure out what was wrong. As was mentioned there, the problem is not in your Java part. You have to change your Javascript logic which builds your CategoryModel on the client side. According to that answer your logic should look like as code which is shown below:

```
var file = ... // your file
var model = {
    id: 'TestId'
    name: 'TestName',
    description: 'TestDesciption',
    .... // other fields are ommited
};

var fd = new FormData();
fd.append('photo', file);
fd.append('model', new Blob([JSON.stringify(model)], { type: "application/json" }));
```

And with this code your exception should be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-file-upload-example/

File Upload Dependency -> Model -> File Upload Controller -> File Upload Validation -> View Page -> Spring Configuration -> Demo

html

```
<form:form method="POST" commandName="fileUploadForm"
    enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <form:errors path="*" cssClass="errorblock" element="div" />

    Please select a file to upload : <input type="file" name="file" />
    <input type="submit" value="upload" />
    <span><form:errors path="file" cssClass="error" />
    </span>

</form:form>
```

pom.xml

```
        <!-- Apache Commons Upload --> 
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.2</version>
</dependency>

<!-- Apache Commons Upload --> 
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.2</version>
</dependency>
```

controller

```
public class FileUploadController extends SimpleFormController{

public FileUploadController(){
    setCommandClass(FileUpload.class);
    setCommandName("fileUploadForm");
}

@Override
protected ModelAndView onSubmit(HttpServletRequest request,
    HttpServletResponse response, Object command, BindException errors)
    throws Exception {

    FileUpload file = (FileUpload)command;

    MultipartFile multipartFile = file.getFile();

    String fileName="";

    if(multipartFile!=null){
        fileName = multipartFile.getOriginalFilename();
        //do whatever you want
    }

    return new ModelAndView("FileUploadSuccess","fileName",fileName);
}
```

model

```
public class FileUpload{

MultipartFile file;
//getter and setter methods
}
```

...

input type="file" **name="file"** ==  private MultipartFile **file**;

controller -> model -> getFile ^^ YES!!!