# Using @RequestParam for multipartfile is a right way?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, multipart

I'm developing a spring mvc application and I want to handle multipart request in my controller. In the request I'm passing `MultiPartFile`  also, currently I'm using `@RequestParam` to get the file parameter, the method look like,

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public def save(
        @ModelAttribute @Valid Product product,
        @RequestParam(value = "image", required = false) MultipartFile file) {
    .....
}
```

Above code works well in my service and the file is getting on the server side. Now somewhere  I saw that in cases that file need to use `@RequestPart` annotation instead of `@RequestParam`. Is there anything wrong to use `@RequestParam` for file ? Or it may cause any kind of error in future?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

It is nothing wrong using `@RequestParam` with `Multipart` file.

> @RequestParam annotation can also be used to associate the part of a
>   "multipart/form-data" request with a method argument supporting the
>   same method argument types. The main difference is that when the
>   method argument is not a String, @RequestParam relies on type
>   conversion via a registered Converter or PropertyEditor while
>   @RequestPart relies on HttpMessageConverters taking into consideration
>   the 'Content-Type' header of the request part. @RequestParam is likely
>   to be used with name-value form fields while @RequestPart is likely to
>   be used with parts containing more complex content (e.g. JSON, XML).

See http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestPart.html

Answer (score 14):

Both of the Annotations can be used, however, you can make your choice about them based on how they interpret arguments internally.

The [Spring Docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestPart.html) states the difference between them very clearly:

> The main difference is that when the method argument is not a String, `@RequestParam` relies on type conversion via a registered Converter or `PropertyEditor` while `@RequestPart` relies on `HttpMessageConverters` taking into consideration the 'Content-Type' header of the request part. `@RequestPara` is likely to be used with name-value form fields while `@RequestPart` is likely to be used with parts containing more complex content (e.g. JSON, XML).

Comment: Clear as mud. I have absolutely no idea what the practical difference is between using a registered converter and using HttpMessageConverters.