# Multipart file (not given condition).Error-400(bad request)

Tags: spring, postman, spring-restcontroller, advanced-rest-client

My rest api is.

```
@PutMapping(consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUEpath="/{referenceNumber}")
public void updateCard(@RequestHeader(value = tenantId) String theTenantId,
@PathVariable String referenceNumber,@RequestParam(value = "card")MultipartFile multipartFile,HttpServletRequest request)
```

I need to check the condition like without browsing the file.

my input format is

**Headers** :

tenantId : ***

**Body**    : selecting "formdata" (Postman), "multipart-formdata" (AdvancedRestClient)

card  : without browsing file

Then i am getting the following error in **Postman**.

```
 {
"timestamp": 1549351840816,
"status": 400,
"error": "Bad Request",
"exception": "org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MissingServletRequestPartException",
"message": "Required request part 'card' is not present",
"path": "/app-1.5.0/1.5/references/34a236d7-9305-402f-959d-8c83d5ededbb"
  }
```

If i try in the AdvancedRest client with same input

I am getting the different error.

```
  {
"timestamp": 1549352119229,
"status": 415,
"error": "Unsupported Media Type",
"exception": "org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException",
"message": "Content type 'null' not supported",
"path": "/app-1.5.0/1.5/references/34a236d7-9305-402f-959d-8c83d5ededbb" 
  
  }
```

Is there any reason for different outputs and can i check the api without
browsing file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```java
@PutMapping(consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUEpath="/{referenceNumber}")
public void updateCard(@RequestHeader(value = tenantId) String theTenantId,
@PathVariable String referenceNumber,@RequestPart(required = false,value = "card")MultipartFile multipartFile,HttpServletRequest request){

}
```

User @RequestPart instead of @RequestParam

Comment: Thank you.. It is working.What is the difference between RequestPart and RequestParam in my case.

Comment: @madhuri [Difference between `@RequestPart` and `@RequestParam`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38156646/using-requestparam-for-multipartfile-is-a-right-way)