# Some problem Logic with response POST in spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, request

I will have to do some development and I will need your logic please,
I'll try to be as clear as possible

I have a JSON file that will be sent to a Web Service to process it.

When the file arrives on this Web Service, I have to parse it.

**First question** :
Is it a  **@PostMapping** to recover this file?

Since it's a file, I get it as a file like this:

```
@PostMapping( value="/getFile",
consumes = {"multipart/form-data"})
public void postFile(@RequestParam() MultipartFile file) throws IOException
```

I recover the file well, but the concern is that the **@RequestParam** parameter expects a file name, except that when the file is sent to the web service, I do not know its name yet,

**Second Question** :

So how do you parse this file into a string?

Thank you in advance for your precious help

Comment: You can find the answer to your doubt with @RequestParam here. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38156646/using-requestparam-for-multipartfile-is-a-right-way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38156646/using-requestparam-for-multipartfile-is-a-right-way)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first question:

Yep, @PostMapping is the right way to go. Regarding the file name bit, @RequestParam() does not expect the file name to be passed, it expects the "key" of the key-value pair where the value is the file being uploaded.
For example, when sending a file via a RestTemplate call, the file would be included in the POST call as somewhat like this:

```
MultiValueMap<String, Object> body = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
body.add("uploadFile", getFileToUpload());
```

Here the key is "uploadFile", so your controller will look like this :

```
@PostMapping( value="/getFile",
consumes = {"multipart/form-data"})
public void postFile(@RequestParam("uploadFile") MultipartFile file) throws IOException
```

Checkout this tutorial : https://spring.io/guides/gs/uploading-files/

---

For the second question:

```
ByteArrayInputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(file.getBytes());
String myFileString = IOUtils.toString(stream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

This should do. Cheers

Comment: Ok I expect that's the name of file !! But it's the key who send in the web service before ! That's it ? thanks a lot