# Spring boot url configure with data and multipartfile

Tags: spring-boot

I have this controller file with the following code

```
@PostMapping(path = "/addDefaultTemplate")
void addDefaultTemplate(@Valid @ModelAttribute AddDefaultTemplate defaultTemplate) throws Exception {
 //Logic
}
```

And i have this AddDefaultTemplate java file

```
@Data
public class AddDefaultTemplate {

@NotBlank
String name;

@NotNull
String category;

@NotNull
String type;

@NotNull
MultipartFile[] file; 
}
```

When i comment the multipartfile configuration in the above class, the url is working fine. If i add the multipartfile in the above class url throws 400 error. Why, what's the reason?

This is the request data.
[image]

Comment: Are you sending any file with field name 'file' with the request?

Comment: yea i'm sending. I have added the request data too.

Comment: refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46517583/spring-cannot-process-multipart-form-data-post-request-error-400-bad-request

Comment: @Alien It worked alien thnx. But it is like splitting the request. But there is no other option like combining into a single file like AddDefaultTemplate class and sending?