# Spring boot send RequestBody and RequestParam

Tags: java, spring, multipartform-data

I'm crating api and I need to send Json (as object) and image file in one request. So here's how I do it.

```
@PostMapping("/upload")
public String singleFileUpload(@RequestBody Item item, @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {
   // logic
}
```

and here how I test this method with Postman

[image]

Here's the headers
[image]

also here's my item object

```
{
    "title": "useruser",
    "description": "Woodfsdfw",
    "img": "www.gosdfsdfsdfsdfog.elt",
    "lat": 45.48745,
    "lng": 96.5651655,
    "user": {
        "name": "Jerry",
        "img" : "sdfsdfdfsdf",
        "email": "jrry@gmail.com"
    }
}
```

So here what I get from server as a response

```
 {
    "timestamp": 1520750026769,
    "status": 415,
    "error": "Unsupported Media Type",
    "exception": "org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException",
    "message": "Content type 'multipart/form-data;boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryYzp58riGtVnLl7mI;charset=UTF-8' not supported",
    "path": "/api/upload"
}
```

I've been struggling with this for 4 hours. Any idea how to fix that? 
EDIT
after I used `Content-Type multipart/form-data` I get this error

```
{
    "timestamp": 1520750811814,
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "exception": "org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException",
    "message": "Could not parse multipart servlet request; nested exception is java.io.IOException: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadException: the request was rejected because no multipart boundary was found",
    "path": "/api/upload"
}
```

Comment: Use `Content-Type` of `multipart/form-data`

Comment: @ShaneCoder I edited my answer. I've tried to use that before. But as I know postman automatically set corrent `Content-Type`

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21329426/spring-mvc-multipart-request-with-json

Answer (score 3):

You should use `@RequestPart` for both your input parameters like:

```
@PostMapping("/upload", consumes = {"multipart/form-data"})
public String singleFileUpload(@RequestPart("item") Item item, @RequestPart("file") MultipartFile file) {
   // logic
}
```

Use a curl request to verify

```
curl -H 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data' -F item='{"key": "value"};type=application/json' -F file='@/path/to/file;type=application/octet-stream' http://'your-url' --trace-ascii -
```

Print the curl trace output if it still doesn't work for you.