# SpringBoot / Fetch : Invalid mime type "undefined": does not contain '/'

Tags: javascript, spring-boot, fetch, mime-types, form-data

I'm trying to make a post request with a form data, containing a file and a Json Object.

To perform this, i set the **Content-Type** to **undefined**, according to the following post
https://stackoverflow.com/a/25183266/4573767

> This causes the browser to set the Content-Type to multipart/form-data
>   and fill the boundary correctly.

However, on the (springboot) server side, i get this error message :

> Resolved exception caused by Handler execution:
>   org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: **Invalid
>   mime type "undefined": does not contain '/'**

So, it seems that the "undefined" content type is not correctly managed by the browser.

Here is the fetch command, on the client side :

```
    // My document blob
    var documentBlob = new Blob([JSON.stringify({ documentName: "toto" })], {
      type: "application/json"
    });

    // My Form data containing a file and the document blob
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("file", this.state.file);
    formData.append("document", documentBlob);

    // Fetch command
    fetch("/document/", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": undefined
      },
      data: formData
    }).then(function(response) {
      console.log("response!");
    });
```

Here is the server side (spring boot rest controller) :

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/document")
public class DocumentController {

    @Autowired
    private DocumentRepository documentRepository;  

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = { "multipart/form-data" })
    public boolean addDocument(@RequestPart("document") Document document, @RequestPart("file") MultipartFile file) {
        documentRepository.save(document);
        return true;
    }
}
```

"Document" is a simple pojo :

```
@Entity
public class Document {
    private String documentName;

    public Document() {
    }

    public Document(String documentName) {
        this.setDocumentName(documentName);
    }

    public String getDocumentName() {
        return documentName;
    }

    public void setDocumentName(String documentName) {
        this.documentName = documentName;
    }
}
```

So, i don't really get if the problem is in the client or server side.

Thanks!

//////////////////////////////

**EDIT :** 
I finally got it working, but ***using axios instead of fecth***:

Here is my finaly spring boot rest controller :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public boolean addDocument(@RequestPart("document") Document document, @RequestPart("file") MultipartFile file) {
        // Do things!
        return true;
    }
```

And my javascript/axios call :

```
var documentBlob = new Blob([JSON.stringify({ documentName: "test" })], {
      type: "application/json"
    });
    var formData = new FormData();

    formData.append("document", documentBlob);
    formData.append("file", this.state.file);

    axios({
      method: "post",
      url: "/document/",
      data: formData,
      config: { headers: { "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data" } }
    })
      .then(response => {
        console.log("it's working!");
        console.log(response);
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got it working, but using axios instead of fecth.

See the edited original post to see my solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is in your spring controller request mapping.
You should not have the mapping to `/` there.

Try this...

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/document")
public class DocumentController {

    @Autowired
    private DocumentRepository documentRepository;  

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = { "multipart/form-data" })
    public boolean addDocument(@RequestPart("properties") Document document, @RequestPart("file") MultipartFile file) {
        documentRepository.save(document);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but it seems the issue is not there.
I think that if the mapping was incorrect, the error should be 404, no?

So, even without the / in the mapping, i still have the error message "Invalid mime type "undefined": does not contain '/'" on server side

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to make that request with the `"multipart/form-data"` content type header?

With that mapping method consuming the defined header, your controller won't be able to parse the request without the proper content type.

Comment: Yeah, i tried it too, but then the server reject my request with the message : "org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadException: **the request was rejected because no multipart boundary was found"**

I finnally got it working using axios (see my edited initial post) instead of fetch. Don't know if it's a fetch problem or my implementation that was faulty...