# Upload file in Spring Boot REST API

Tags: spring-boot, file-upload

I am trying to upload a file using Spring Boot `@RestController`:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/register", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public AppResponse registerUserFromApp(
        @RequestBody UserInfo userInfo,
        @RequestParam(value = "file", required = false) CommonsMultipartFile file,
        @RequestParam(value = "inviteCode", required = false) String inviteCode){
```

With this definition, I tried this Postman request:
[image: Register API]
This doesn't work.

I tried adding this to my `RequestMapping`:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/register", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "multipart/form-data")
```

This gives me the same error.

For `userInfo`, I am sending the values as JSON in form-data fields itself as suggested by [another SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43786496/3913366). Doesn't work, same error.

As suggested in some other SO answers, I also made sure that I wasn't sending any headers in Postman.

I tried adding the following property in `application.properties` as well:

```
spring.http.multipart.enabled=false
```

Same error. I also tried `MultipartFile` instead of `CommonsMultipartFile`, no difference at all.

What am I doing wrong? I want to send an image as a File and `UserInfo` object in the request as well. Postman examples will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multipart form data with custom object will be accepted as string. so your controller would be like as follows.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/register", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public AppResponse registerUserFromApp(
    @RequestBody String userInfo,
    @RequestParam(value = "file", required = false) CommonsMultipartFile file,
    @RequestParam(value = "inviteCode", required = false) String inviteCode){

    ObjectMapper obj=new ObjectMapper();
    UserInfo userInfo=obj.readValue(clientData, UserInfo.class);

}
```

you will have to convert String to pojo by using ObjectMapper. Hope this will help.

Comment: Or else check this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21329426/spring-mvc-multipart-request-with-json

Answer (score 0):

I done by adding the Multiple part file in DTO-Bean and adding each field in postman as string. spring boot will match the file and assign the value see the below example

> This is my Account Bean for accept the request from the postman

```
// done test 100%
@JsonPropertyOrder({ "email", "password", "file" })
public class AccountBean {

    @ApiModelProperty(notes = "Enter Email", name = "email", value = "nabeel.amd93@gmail.com", required = true)
    @NotNull(message = "Email contain null")
    @NotBlank(message = "Email Contain blank")
    @Email(message = "Email wrong type")
    private String email;

    @ApiModelProperty(notes = "Enter Password", name = "password", value = "ballistic", required = true)
    @NotNull(message = "Password contain null")
    @NotBlank(message = "Password contain blank")
    private String password;

    @ApiModelProperty(notes = "Enter file", name = "file", value = "xyz", required = true)
    @NotNull(message = "File contain null")
    @ValidImage(message = "File support type => \"image/jpeg\", \"image/png\", \"image/jpg\"")
    private MultipartFile file;

    public AccountBean() { }

    public String getEmail() { return email; }
    public void setEmail(String email) { this.email = email; }

    public String getPassword() { return password; }
    public void setPassword(String password) { this.password = password; }

    public MultipartFile getFile() { return file; }
    public void setFile(MultipartFile file) { this.file = file; }

    @Override
    public String toString() { return "AccountBean{" + "email='" + email + '\'' + ", password='" + password + '\'' + ", repository=" + file + '}'; }

}
```

> Rest-Api

```
@ApiOperation(value = "File upload with object field", response = APIResponse.class)
@ApiResponses(value = {
        @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "Success", response = String.class),
        @ApiResponse(code = 404, message = "Not Found")})
@RequestMapping(value = "/save/account/local", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<APIResponse<?>> saveAccountWithSingleFile(
        @ApiParam(name = "account", value = "Select File with Dto field", required = true)
        @Valid AccountBean accountBean, BindingResult bindingResult) throws IllegalBeanFieldException {
    long sTime = System.nanoTime();
    logger.info("save file with account process");
    if(bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        AtomicInteger bind = new AtomicInteger();
        HashMap<String, HashMap<String, Object>> error = new HashMap<>();
        bindingResult.getFieldErrors().forEach(fieldError -> {
            String key = "key-"+bind;
            HashMap<String, Object> value = new HashMap<>();
            value.put("objectName", fieldError.getObjectName());
            value.put("field", fieldError.getField() != null ? fieldError.getField() : "null");
            value.put("reject", fieldError.getRejectedValue() != null ? fieldError.getRejectedValue() : "null");
            value.put("message", fieldError.getDefaultMessage());
            error.put(key, value);
            bind.getAndIncrement();
        });
        throw new IllegalBeanFieldException(error.toString());
    }
    this.apiResponse = this.uploadFile(accountBean.getFile()).getBody();
    logger.debug("account file save time " + ((System.nanoTime() - sTime) / 1000000) + ".ms");

    if(this.apiResponse.getReturnCode().equals(HttpStatus.OK)) {
        // add-info to the account
        Account account = new Account();
        account.setEmail(accountBean.getEmail());
        account.setPassword(accountBean.getPassword());
        account.setFileInfo((FileInfo) this.apiResponse.getEntity());
        account = this.iAccountService.saveAccount(account);
        logger.info("account with file single file info save time :- " + ((System.nanoTime() - sTime) / 1000000) + ".ms");
        this.apiResponse = new APIResponse<Account>("File save with account", HttpStatus.OK, account);
        logger.info("account added " + this.apiResponse.toString());
        logger.info("total response time :- " + ((System.nanoTime() - sTime) / 1000000) + ".ms");
   }

    return new ResponseEntity<APIResponse<?>>(this.apiResponse, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

> PostMan Input

[image]

> https://github.com/NABEEL-AHMED-JAMIL/fserver project for example