# How to send @Requestbody and @Requestpart together in spring

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, curl

I want to pass json and file together in the controller using curl. I have following method in controller.

```
@PostMapping(value = /api/campaign, headers = {"content-type=multipart/mixed","content-type=multipart/form-data"})
    @ResponseBody
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    public @Valid ResponseDTO campaignCreator (@Valid @RequestBody CampaignCreatorDTO campaignCreatorDTO, @RequestPart("file") MultipartFile adGraphic){
}
```

Below is the curl command

```
curl -i -X POST -H "Content-Type: multipart/mixed" -d "campaignCreatorDTO={\"edipi\":123456789,\"firstName\":\"John\",\"lastName\":\"Smith\",\"email\":\"john.smith@gmail.com\"};type=application/json" -F "file=@newfile.png;type=image/png"  http://localhost:8080/api/campaign
```

controller method is not getting called.
when I put json in a file and use file in curl command in place of direct json it works.
But I do not want to use file for json.

I tried to use @RequestPart for json object but same issue.

is there any way to pass multipart file inside json I mean CampaignCreatorDTO object?

Update:: Now I am able to pass RequestPart for both type but image size is coming 0 bytes. Though iamge is present in the filesystem.

Updated Code ::
now using below code, and getting filesize as 0 bytes.

```
@PostMapping(value = /api/campaign, consumes = {"multipart/form-data","multipart/mixed"})
    @ResponseBody
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    public @Valid ResponseDTO campaignCreator (@Valid @RequestPart("json") CampaignCreatorDTO campaignCreatorDTO, @RequestPart("file") MultipartFile adGraphic) {
}
```

I tried solution given in this link but still same issue

[Spring MVC Multipart Request with JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21329426/spring-mvc-multipart-request-with-json)

this is how client is paasing the data to server

```
let formData = new FormData()

const blob = new Blob([json], {
type: 'application/json'
});

formData.append("json", blob)
formData.append("file", values.adCreativeImageCover)

let authToken = sessionStorage.getItem("authToken")

fetch(/api/campaign, {
method: "POST",
headers: {
'Accept': 'application/json',
'X-Auth-Token': authToken,
},
mode: 'cors',
body: formData
})
```

Comment: You request can't be `multipart/form-data` and `application/json` at the same time. You can either do it with two requests or send the json with request parameters

Comment: you just need to encode either your json (to a URL compatible format, e.g. URL encode) or your file(to something like base64 string) and decode it on server

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21329426/spring-mvc-multipart-request-with-json

Comment: @SumeshTG Doing same, but still getting file size as 0 bytes.

Comment: @Anjali Your request body should have formData not JSON.

Comment: @SumeshTG I want both in one request. @RequestPart("json") CampaignCreatorDTO campaignCreatorDTO, @RequestPart("file") MultipartFile adGraphic

Comment: @Anjali  Ya. It is possible using `ajax` and formData. How you pass data to the server?

Comment: Please check updated the question with client code

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved the issue by implementing multipartresolver in configuration.

```
@Bean
    public MultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
        return new StandardServletMultipartResolver();
    }
```

Comment: hey
can you explain this more?
I am also facing the same issue

Comment: No surprise to see zero upvote. More details are required

Comment: add in the details. Its incomplete.

Answer (score -1):

**First way:**
If you will use postman/javaScript framework -> you have to define media-type of every RequestPart. example in POSTMAN:
[image]

**Second way** is implement maintaining of octet-stream, because spring set it by default in `AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver.class` if there is no content-type header in request part.
(I'm using  `spring-boot-starter-parent 2.4.1 -> spring-webmvc 5.3.2`)
[image: Y]

**So here is 2 cases I found (to map response JSON to DTO):**

**1 case** (not recommended):
Set supporting to JSON converter:
[image]

**2 case:**
Define new Converter class which will work definitely for needed classes (in my case it is `MDVersionDTO.class`) and definitely when it comes like ***octet-stream***, to implement it, ovveride `canRead()` method.
[image]