# Is it possible to define an end point in a Controller with a RequestBody and a RequestPart?

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat9

I need to create a single end point that accepts a RequestBody OR a RequestPart.

If the request contains the RequestPart it will execute some logic to process the MultipartFile otherwise it will process the object passed in the RequestBody.

I checked [How to send @Requestbody and @Requestpart together in spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53005240/how-to-send-requestbody-and-requestpart-together-in-spring) but it differs from my question because I don't want to send both, RequestBody and RequestPart, at the same time.

I defined my entry point as:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/xyz/api/{endPoint}", method= RequestMethod.POST)
public void endPointPost(
        @PathVariable String endPoint,
        HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response,
        @RequestBody(required=false) Object body,
        @RequestPart(required=false) MultipartFile uploadFile) throws Exception {
```

If the request contains only the RequestBody it works correctly, for instance:

`{"body":{"companyCD":"myTest"}}`

However, when sending the multipart request it fails with the follwing error:

```
2019-10-18 00:50:43,440 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-8] org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMapping: Mapped to public void com.monoplus.mcd.rest.GenericController.endPointPost(java.lang.String,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse,java.lang.Object,org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile) throws java.lang.Exception
2019-10-18 00:50:43,440 INFO  [http-nio-8080-exec-8] com.monoplus.mcd.rest.ServletControllerInterceptor: ServletControllerInterceptor - preHandle
2019-10-18 00:50:43,442 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-8] org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod: Could not resolve parameter [3] in public void com.monoplus.mcd.rest.GenericController.endPointPost(java.lang.String,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse,java.lang.Object,org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile) throws java.lang.Exception: Content type 'multipart/form-data;boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryG1Xr4xtC2rNYWuCd;charset=UTF-8' not supported
2019-10-18 00:50:43,446 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-8] org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver: Using @ExceptionHandler public final org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.lang.Object> org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ResponseEntityExceptionHandler.handleException(java.lang.Exception,org.springframework.web.context.request.WebRequest) throws java.lang.Exception
2019-10-18 00:50:43,481 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-8] org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor: No match for [text/html, application/xhtml+xml, image/webp, image/apng, application/signed-exchange;v=b3, application/xml;q=0.9, */*;q=0.8], supported: []
2019-10-18 00:50:43,482 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-8] org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver: Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'multipart/form-data;boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryG1Xr4xtC2rNYWuCd;charset=UTF-8' not supported]
2019-10-18 00:50:43,483 INFO  [http-nio-8080-exec-8] com.monoplus.mcd.rest.ServletControllerInterceptor: ServletControllerInterceptor - afterCompletion - org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter$SessionRepositoryResponseWrapper@6c9a1e05
2019-10-18 00:50:43,484 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-8] org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet: Completed 415 UNSUPPORTED_MEDIA_TYPE
```

Please note that `Could not resolve parameter [3]...` refers to the RequestBody parameter.

This is my multipart request:

- Header

```
Host: localhost:88
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:69.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/69.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------262541039624932
Content-Length: 1401
Connection: keep-alive
Referer: http://localhost:88/appl/html/master/FileImport.html
Cookie: JSESSIONID=3f052417-1702-48b6-b7c2-cac5609ef525; SESSION=M2YwNTI0MTctMTcwMi00OGI2LWI3YzItY2FjNTYwOWVmNTI1
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

- Body

```
-----------------------------262541039624932
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="uploadFile"; filename="testFile.txt"
Content-Type: text/plain


1 - File content

-----------------------------262541039624932
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="_ns"


-----------------------------262541039624932
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="_qt"

false
-----------------------------262541039624932
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="_body"

{"USER_NAME":""}
-----------------------------262541039624932--
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I'm thinking about this question from a RESTful point of view and not necessarily spring.  If you are 1) trying to create or edit (post or put) a resource or 2) trying to upload a file; shouldn't those be two different URI Paths?

Comment: I kind of agree, but there are two things, first there are specifications and second as the end point is defined with a PathVariable the servlet will take the decision where to send the request. In this case, I just want a single entry point instead of multiple RestControllers.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Chris suggestion I was able to solve my question, I defined a different entry point for the Multipart content.

```
    @RequestMapping(value="/xyz/api/{endPoint}", method= RequestMethod.POST, consumes = {"multipart/form-data"})
    public void multiPartEndPointPost(
            @PathVariable String endPoint,
            HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response
    ) throws Exception {

        this.doSomeStuff(endPoint, request, response);
    }
```

The important part is the `consumes = {"multipart/form-data"}` then I can use Apache Commons FileUpload to upload the files.

The answer for [[Cannot use Apache Commons FileUpload with Spring Boot multipart.resolve-lazily](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54813440/cannot-use-apache-commons-fileupload-with-spring-boot-multipart-resolve-lazily/54942568#54942568]) also helped me to solve my question.