# Java, Rest API, multipart

Tags: java, json, rest, spring-boot

I want to save an entity in DB. The entity has several fields and photo (photo I will save in byte[]). I wrote a `RestController`, but it hasn't worked. 
Format `JSON`, I use postman, in `form-data` I add a file, in raw I put body and use `JSON`.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/upload", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = {"multipart/form-data"})
@ResponseBody
public void storeAd(@RequestPart("client") @Valid Client client, @RequestPart("file") @Valid MultipartFile file) throws IOException {
    Client myClient = client;
    byte[] s = file.getBytes();
    int a = s.length;

}
```

> I see error:
>   Resolved exception caused by handler execution:

```
org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException:
    Content type 'application/json' not supported
```

Request from postman[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wHUPl.png)

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! I would start by checking the data coming in. HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException is just what it says, wrong type of data coming in

Comment: You can try and use, "consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE".

Comment: I tried "consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE" and saw
org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'application/json' not supported

Comment: It's a duplicate. Please find how to send mixin requests here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25183266/3439496

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add "Content-Type : application/x-www-form-urlencoded" in header section.