# How to receive request body data along with multi-part image file?

Tags: java, spring-boot, multipartform-data

I want to receive multi-part image file with request body data, but could not able to figure it out, why it is throwing `org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'application/octet-stream'` not supported exception

Below is my implementation

```
public ResponseEntity<GlobalResponse> createUser(@Valid @RequestPart("json") UserDTO userDTO ,@RequestPart(value ="file", required=false)MultipartFile file) throws IOException {

      //Calling some service

      return new ResponseEntity<>( HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

EDIT:
This is my postman configuration

[image]

Comment: what do you mean by not working? does it throws any error? please elaborate more

Comment: show us your client implementation please

Comment: @Mustahsan It is throwing org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'application/octet-stream' not supported exception

Comment: can u share RequestMapping configuration you use above this method?

Comment: @ValentynRiabukhin Right now, I am testing the API with Postman

Comment: Can you check the headers you are specifying? Or can you share your headers here.

Comment: @Mustahsan I am using @Postmapping("/api/v1/user) instead of request mapping

Comment: okay, check my answer

Comment: @cameCode could u generate request payload from postman and show it? I think u can find solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21329426/spring-mvc-multipart-request-with-json

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're sending data in **form-data** which can send data in key-value pairs. Not in `RequestBody` so you need to modify your endpoint like this:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/createUser")
public ResponseEntity createUser(@RequestParam("json") String json, @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) throws IOException {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    UserDTO userDTO = objectMapper.readValue(json, UserDTO.class);
    // Do something
    return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

You need to receive your `UserDTO` object in `String` representation and then map it to `UserDTO` using `ObjectMapper`. This will allow you to receive `MultipartFile` and `UserDTO` using form-data.

Comment: Can you tell me , what is package name of ObjectMapper class as there are multiple ObjectMapper class

Comment: @camelCode `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind`

Comment: @camelCode I'm glad to know that.

Comment: Do you know any alternative solution, actually I want to send data as @Requestbody with the image file

Comment: @camelCode with `@RequestBody` you can't send `MultipartFile`.

Answer (score 0):

As per your exception: `org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'application/octet-stream'` the method is not expecting a multipart data so,

Specify request to consume `MultiPart` data in `@RequestMapping` configuration:

```
@Postmapping("/api/v1/user", consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE) 
public ResponseEntity<GlobalResponse> createUser(@Valid @RequestPart("json") UserDTO userDTO ,@RequestPart(value ="file", required=false)MultipartFile file) throws IOException {

      //Calling some service

      return new ResponseEntity<>( HttpStatus.OK);
}
```