# com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile`

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot

I'm trying to access an uploaded file from the spring boot controller, but I'm getting error

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile
```

FormDomain class

```
public class FormDomain {
     @JsonPropertyDescription
 private MultipartFile fileInput;

public MultipartFile getFileInput() {
    return fileInput;
}

public void setFileInput(MultipartFile fileInput) {
    this.fileInput = fileInput;
}

}
```

Form Controller Class

```
@CrossOrigin(origins="*")
@RestController
public class FormController {
      @PostMapping(path="/basicForm")
 public String postResponseController(
              @RequestBody FormDomain loginForm) throws IOException {
         return "file transfer completed successfully";
     }
```

Angular form

```
<form #basicForm = "ngForm" (ngSubmit) = "onClickSubmit(basicForm.value)" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-horizontal">
    <input type="file" id="file-input" name="fileInput" ngModel (change)="selectFile($event)">
     <button type="submit"> Submit</button>
 </form>
```

Select File method

```
 selectFile(event) {
    this.selectedFiles = event.target.files[0];
    console.log(this.selectedFiles);
    }
```

Angular method that submits form

```
   onClickSubmit(data) {
             data.fileInput=this.selectedFiles;
        this.http.post("http://localhost:8080/basicForm", data).subscribe( (ob)=>(console.log("subscribe method called")));

  }
```

How to solve this issue?

Comment: This answer should help: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21329426/spring-mvc-multipart-request-with-json/25183266#25183266](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21329426/spring-mvc-multipart-request-with-json/25183266#25183266)

Answer (score 0):

That is Not possible with RequestBody annotation.

You can achive  with using like below.

```
public String postResponseController(@RequestParam("multipartFile") MultipartFile multipartFile) throws IOException {
//do somthing
}
```

I hope this will helpful for you.

Comment: yes, it works fine for single and multiple file/files uploads.I am using for working fine