# Webflux: pass files and DTO into single request

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux, spring-rest

I need to pass both file (through `form-data`) and DTO. So I try to do the following:

```java
@PostMapping
public Mono<Void> method(@RequestPart("files") Flux<FilePart> files,
                         Dto dto) {
    return Mono.empty();
}
```

and initialize `Dto` through parameters for each `dto`'s field.

So I get the following error:

```
org.springframework.core.codec.CodecException: Type definition error: [simple type, class org.springframework.http.codec.multipart.SynchronossPartHttpMessageReader$SynchronossFilePart]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: No serializer found for class org.springframework.http.codec.multipart.SynchronossPartHttpMessageReader$SynchronossFilePart and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) (through reference chain: java.util.LinkedHashMap["errors"]->java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableList[0]->org.springframework.validation.FieldError["rejectedValue"])
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: No serializer found for class org.springframework.http.codec.multipart.SynchronossPartHttpMessageReader$SynchronossFilePart and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) (through reference chain: java.util.LinkedHashMap["errors"]->java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableList[0]->org.springframework.validation.FieldError["rejectedValue"])
```

Images are loaded correctly if I remove `Dto` parameter completely.

Adding `@RequestBody` annotation to the `Dto` parameter produces the following error:

```
Content type 'multipart/form-data;charset=UTF-8;boundary=rh4lsv9DycBf8hpV2snhKfRjSrj1GvHzVy' not supported for bodyType=com.example.Dto
```

Got this working by passing `Dto` as `@RequestParam("dto") String dto` and parsing JSON manually, but it is not really a perfect solution.

Comment: Have you tried do add `@RequestBody` for your Dto ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you need so called mixed multipart

```
@PostMapping("/test")
public Mono<Void> method(@RequestPart("dto") Dto dto, @RequestPart("files") Flux<FilePart> files) {

    return Mono.empty();
}
```

this works with this http request:

```
POST /test HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 425629ec-335f-4d49-8df4-d6130af67889

------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="files"; filename="Capture.PNG"
Content-Type: image/png


------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="dto"
Content-Type: application/json

{"test":"aaa"}

###
```

Note:

```
   Content-Type: application/json
```

for dto part is **mandatory**

See this answer:

[Spring MVC Multipart Request with JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21329426/spring-mvc-multipart-request-with-json)

Comment: This is working for `String` parts, but in my case I'm getting this error `Content type 'text/plain;charset=UTF-8' not supported for bodyType=com.example.Dto`

Comment: add  Content-Type: application/json to your dto part