# Mapping multipart form-data to object

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have to write a REST API whcih consumes `multipart/form-data`. When I write the method like below , it works fine

```
@RequestMapping(value="/addSftp", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public HashMap<String, Object> welcome( HttpServletRequest request,@RequestParam(value="selectedFile", required=false) MultipartFile selectedFile,
        @RequestParam(value="sftp_name") String sftp_name,
        @RequestParam(value="ip_address")String ip_address,
        @RequestParam(value="port_number")String port_number,
        @RequestParam(value="userName")String userName,
        @RequestParam(value="password")String password,
        @RequestParam(value="customRadioInline1")String customRadioInline1) {
    HashMap map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    System.out.println(sftp_name);
    System.out.println(ip_address);
    System.out.println(port_number);
    System.out.println(userName);
    System.out.println(password);
    System.out.println(customRadioInline1);
    System.out.println(selectedFile);
    map.put("stat", "success");
     return map;
              }
```

I want to map the request to a bean. Below is my bean

```
public class SftpBean {

    private String sftp_name;
    private String ip_address; 
    private String port_number;
    private String userName;
    private String password;
    private String customRadioInline1;
    private MultipartFile selectedFile;

//getters and setters here

}
```

But when I write the method like below , I am getting exception

```
public HashMap<String, Object> welcome( @RequestBody SftpBean sftpBean) {
    HashMap map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    System.out.println(sftpBean.getIpAddress());
    //similar statements for priniting other parameters
    map.put("stat", "success");
     return map;
}
```

Here is my exception

```
Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: 
    Content type 'multipart/form-data;boundary=---------------------------246741595337214313524058968681;charset=UTF-8' not supported]
```

Here is my request payload

```
-----------------------------317042354532732980343175029806
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="sftp_name"

ABC
-----------------------------317042354532732980343175029806
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="ip_address"

123
-----------------------------317042354532732980343175029806
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="port_number"

456
-----------------------------317042354532732980343175029806
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="userName"

demo
-----------------------------317042354532732980343175029806
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="password"

demo123
-----------------------------317042354532732980343175029806
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="customRadioInline1"

pwd
-----------------------------317042354532732980343175029806
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="selectedFile"; filename="details.txt"
Content-Type: text/plain
```

Is there a way to directly map the request to my `SftpBean`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring MVC Multipart Request with JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21329426/spring-mvc-multipart-request-with-json)

Comment: @KavithaKarunakaran I am just printing out the variable names in logic. However I will add it

Comment: @srinivaschaitanya - The error says that your content type is not supported at the server end. Also, from the sample code it is not evident whether you have used `@Consumes` to specify the content type accepted by the welcome method in your RestController

Comment: @KavithaKarunakaran tried using consumes=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE
But I got the same error

Comment: Ok. You need to do the following two things - a). change the consumes to `MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON` instead of ``MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE``. b). Change the payload from multipart form to json format.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `RequestPart` for body you are sending along with `MultipartFile`.

Here is how i have done it:

```java
@PostMapping("/hello/upload")
public SftpBean upload(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file,
                      @RequestPart("body") SftpBean sftpBean) {
    return sftpBean;
}
```

Pojo remains the same.

Request in postman:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `@Consumes` or `consumes=` inside `@RequestMapping` to specify the content type acceptable by the server end. If you are sending multipart form data, you can use `MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA` if you are sending the request as multipart form. However, if you are encapsulating that into an object and sending it as json, you need to use `MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON`.

Also ensure that the right format is sent from the client side which consumes the `RestController`. You need to change the payload from multipart form to json format at client end while creating the REST request. The modified method :

```
public HashMap<String, Object> welcome( @RequestBody SftpBean sftpBean)
```

expects only a json object `SftpBean` which is not at all found in your payload.