# Spring-boot rest api send file and additional data

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I want to upload file with additional info. I have controller:

```
@PostMapping(value = "file", consumes = {MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE,MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE})
public void uploadRecipe(@RequestPart MultipartFile multipartFile, @RequestPart UploadFileRequest uploadFileRequest ) {
 ...
}
```

POJO

```
public class UploadFileRequest {
    private String title;
    private String text;

    //getters and setters
}
```

And i am sending request via postman:

[image]

however all i get is:

> Resolved
> [org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MissingServletRequestPartException:
> Required request part 'uploadFileRequest ' is not present]

Why isnt the `uploadFileRequest` mapped? It is valid json.

Thanks for help!

Comment: Which Content-Type are you sending?

Comment: The same issue explain in another post.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21329426/spring-mvc-multipart-request-with-json

Answer (score 0):

First, you can drop the `consumes` from your RequestMapping, Spring expects that @RequestParts are being sent in the form of `multipart/form-data`, you don't need to explicitly call this out (Also, you have a value set here that's not valid for this type of input).

Second, in postman, go to your headers and set `Content-Type` to `multipart/form-data`, you should be good to go.